# Beginner Issue with Mongoose and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Node, along with Mongoose and MongoDB. I'm trying to test inserting data into one of the collections in a database on MongoDB Atlas. However, the code somehow inserts the data into the wrong database. I intend to insert data into the '`test`' collection in the '`quizzard`' database. However, a new collection called '`tests`' was created within `quizzard` where the data was placed. When I tried it again, it started inserting data into another database called 'test' and created a collection called 'tests', where the data is still being placed.

```js
var link = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@quizzard-dp0b2.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
// changed to <user> and <password> for privacy reasons

mongoose.connect(link, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Connected');
});

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const TestSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  data: String
});

//TestSchema.set('database', 'test');
//TestSchema.set('collection', 'test');

const Test = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema);
const data = {
  _id: 11,
  data: "why???"
};

const newTest = new Test(data);
newTest.save((error) => {
 if(error){
   console.log("An error has occured");
 } else {
   console.log("Action performed");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the link; after the first slash, you choose which DB you want to use.

Examples

```
// DB NAME youinsertinheredbname
var link = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@quizzard-dp0b2.mongodb.net/youinsertinheredbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority";


// DB NAME stackoverflow
var link = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@quizzard-dp0b2.mongodb.net/stackoverflow?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```